# Filter DataGridView by calculated column

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview, filter

I have a sql database where field in table A is calculated (bit type) from table B.  So column A.CalcActive is the result of a scalar function that pulls the value from table B.

I then have a datagridview of table A in vb.net and want to filter it based on A.CalcActive.    Trying that in vb.net like this:

```
AListBindingSource.Filter = "calcActive=1"
```

Error message is CANNOT FIND COLUMN CALCACTIVE

Checking datagridview, that is the name of the column (and of the field), and I can filter on other fields easily, so it occurs to me that I should not be trying to filter on a calculated field.  Is that the issue?

Should I do this with an inner join instead?  I think I saw a post on how to do that in a datagridview, which is probably better anyway?

Comment: Well, for now, I created a VIEW in SQL based on the INNER JOIN and then set the datagridview to pull from the view instead of the table.   Then filtering is easy, and I avoid scalar function calculations.   Not sure it is best, but it works at least.